# Losing value of $var when array is used

Tags: php, variables, concatenation

Im trying to construct a url like:

```
https://theserver/career/pathway?path=3&edu=4&cert=
```

The overarching issue here is the `$message` var is losing the values of  `$pathval` , `$edval`, `$certval` when populated into the array ala `$data` (as shown below)

**When using your last code block**

```
else if ($action == "send") {
    //added
    #pathway var
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    $pathval = $_SESSION['pathid'];
    $edval = $_SESSION['edid'];
    $certval = $_SESSION['certid'];

    var_dump($pathval);
    var_dump($edval);
    var_dump($certval);

    $data = array(
        "path"=>$pathval,
        "edu"=>$edval,
        "cert"=>$certval
    );

    var_dump($data);


    $server_prefix = 'https://';
    $server_address = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];

    #$fullurl = $server_prefix.$server_address."/career/pathway?ed=".$edval;

    // Send the email
    $name = isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : "";
    $email = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : "";
    $subject = isset($_POST["subject"]) ? $_POST["subject"] : $subject;
    $message = $server_prefix.$server_address.'/career/pathway?'.http_build_query($data);
    var_dump($message);
    // $message = $pathval;
    var_dump($message);

    $cc = isset($_POST["cc"]) ? $_POST["cc"] : "";
    $token = isset($_POST["token"]) ? $_POST["token"] : "";

    // make sure the token matches
    if ($token === smcf_token($to)) {
        smcf_send($name, $email, $subject, $message, $cc);
        echo "Your message was successfully sent.";
        // echo $name . "\n";
        // echo $email . "\n";
        // echo $subject . "\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "Unfortunately, your message could not be verified.";
    }
}
```

This outputs (this outputs great!):

```
array(3) { ["pathid"]=> string(1) "3" ["edid"]=> string(1) "4" ["certid"]=> string(0) "" } string(1) "3" string(1) "4" string(0) "" array(3) { ["path"]=> string(1) "3" ["edu"]=> string(1) "4" ["cert"]=> string(0) "" } string(56) "https://theserver/career/pathway?path=3&edu=4&cert=" string(56) "https://theserver/career/pathway?path=3&edu=4&cert=" Your message was successfully sen
```

**The email output is**: `Message: https://theserver/career/pathway?path=edu=cert`

Comment: Have you put `session_start()` at the top of your page?

Comment: This really looks strange. How do you output those strings ?

Comment: Yes the session is created and the values are coming in on the first "if I try"

Comment: How do you store pathval in $_SESSION['pathid'], for instance?

Comment: Note that the pipe character (`|`) is invalid in a URL and must be urlencoded. Take a look at [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Comment: $_SESSION['pathid']=$path; is created by a php script that is linked through form submission

Comment: So maybe it lacks "session_start()", just like @Jay Blanchard says.

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley - regardless of the characters used the values arent being shown in "If I try:" 1 and 2

Comment: Can you show us more of the code @user2107529?

Comment: @user2107529 That's why I posted it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @NunoCosta session_start() is used on all pages that $_SESSION is used.

Comment: (1) What does `print_r($_SESSION);` output?  (2) Have you tried a `print_r($_POST);` (or `$_GET`) in the script affecting values from posted form to session variable? --> Some steps to find out where the values got lost or didn't pass through...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment yet.

But as @JeremiahWinsley said:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

```
$pathval = 3;
    $edval = 4;
    $certval = '';
    $server_prefix = 'https://';
    $server_address = 'website.com';
   $data = array('path'=>$pathval,
        'edu'=>$edval,
        'cert'=>$certval);

    echo $server_prefix.$server_address.'/career/pathway?'.http_build_query($data) . "\n";
    echo $server_prefix.$server_address.'/career/pathway?'.http_build_query($data, '', '&amp;');
```

output:

```
https://website.com/career/pathway?path=3&edu=4&cert=
https://website.com/career/pathway?path=3&amp;edu=4&amp;cert=
```

is that what you asked for?

Your Question phph CODE must be like this:

```
if ($action == "send") {
        // VALUES EXIST HERE
        var_dump($_SESSION);
        $pathval = $_SESSION['pathid'];
        $edval = $_SESSION['edid'];
        $certval = $_SESSION['certid'];
        var_dump($pathval);
        var_dump($edval);
        var_dump($certval);

        // << LOSING THE VALUES HERE >>
        $data = array(
            "path"=>$pathval,
            "edu"=>$edval,
            "cert"=>$certval
        );
        var_dump($data);
        // This DOES NOT work, and outputs: `path=edu=cert`
        $message = http_build_query($data);
        var_dump($message);
        // This DOES work and outputs: `3`
        $message = $pathval;
            var_dump($message);
exit;
        }
```

so now with all these echos and your php code everything is clear!!!
just be attentive!

your code must be:

```
else if ($action == "send") {
//added

$pathval = $_SESSION['pathid'];
$edval = $_SESSION['edid'];
$certval = $_SESSION['certid'];

var_dump($pathval);
var_dump($edval);
var_dump($certval);

$data = array(
    "path"=>$pathval,
    "edu"=>$edval,
    "cert"=>$certval
);

var_dump($data);

$server_prefix = 'https://';
$server_address = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];

// Send the email
$name = isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : "";
$email = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : "";
$subject = isset($_POST["subject"]) ? $_POST["subject"] : $subject;
$message = $server_prefix.$server_address.'/career/pathway?'.http_build_query($data);
var_dump($message);

$cc = isset($_POST["cc"]) ? $_POST["cc"] : "";
$token = isset($_POST["token"]) ? $_POST["token"] : "";

// make sure the token matches
if ($token === smcf_token($to)) {
    smcf_send($name, $email, $subject, $message, $cc);
    echo "Your message was successfully sent.";
}
else {
        echo "Unfortunately, your message could not be verified.";
    }
}
```

and if it works - you can remove the rest var_dump lines

Comment: What? Its still not sending the values

Comment: See the section: "This outputs"

Comment: the last sentence in your question is "The email output is: Message: https://theserver/career/pathway?path=edu=cert" that can not be true! because we see that messagw include an IP adderess not "theserver" - so did you check last email in your inbox?

Comment: Yes I did. The php is gathering the IP address of the server and im overwriting the server ip with "theserver" when i post

Comment: WHAT???? you overriting it where? how can i help you debug if you change something without notice? Do you really use the same php code here on the page and on your server? or you do some manual transformation every time? I can't help you if you don't want to help me

Comment: When i post the output and code of mine I removed the ip address of my server as it isnt needed. Is what im saying

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68399/discussion-on-answer-by-kim-alexander-losing-value-of-var-when-array-is-used).